# sum of table with join on joined table gives wrong total

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

1. users_timings_log
2. projects_tasks
3. projects_modules

I want to calculate the total hours spent on a task with module_ id 2 for example

I use the following query for it:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start_date`, `end_date`)))
AS `total_hours`
FROM `users_timings_log`
INNER JOIN `projects_tasks` ON users_timings_log.type_id = projects_tasks.id
LEFT JOIN `projects_modules` ON projects_tasks.module_id = '2'
WHERE `type` = '0'
```

This is the structure of my `users_timings_log` table

```
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------+---------+
|   ID  | start_date          | end_date            | type | type_id |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------+---------+
|   1   | 2015-09-17 09:00:00 | 2015-09-17 19:00:00 | 1    | 28      |
|   2   | 2015-09-17 07:00:00 | 2015-09-17 12:00:00 | 1    | 24      |
|   3   | 2015-09-17 08:00:00 | 2015-09-17 16:15:00 | 1    | 18      |
|   4   | 2015-09-17 10:00:00 | 2015-09-17 17:00:00 | 1    | 24      |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------+---------+
```

Here's the structure of my `projects_tasks` table

```
+-------+---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+
|   ID  | name          | description                 | module_id |
+-------+---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+
|   18  | First task    | Some useless description    | 1         |
|   24  | Second task   | Another useless description | 2         |
|   28  | Third task    | NULL                        | 3         |
+-------+---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+
```

Structure of `projects_modules` table

```
+-------+---------------+
|   ID  | name          |
+-------+---------------+
|   1   | Module 1      |
|   2   | Module 2      |
|   3   | Module 3      |
+-------+---------------+
```

What I need is the total of hours of a specific module, but for some reason It is giving me for each module the same amount of time.

I'm stuck on it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: and users_timings_log.id is always 1 (like type)?

Comment: sorry, i'll change that

Comment: yes type is in this case always 1 because. It used to be enum (0,1) but decided to undo the 0. I'll change that later.

Comment: `WHERE type = '0'` will yield interesting results then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` and proper `JOIN`:

```
SELECT pt.module_id,
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, ul.`start_date`, ul.`end_date`)))
AS `total_hours`
FROM `users_timings_log` ul INNER JOIN
     `projects_tasks` pt
     ON ul.type_id = pt.id 
WHERE `type` = '0'
GROUP BY pt.module_id;
```

If you only want one module, then add a `WHERE` clause for that purpose.

I also added table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.

I should add, the problem with your query is that it did not have proper `JOIN` conditions for `projects_modules`.  You don't seem to need that table, so removing the table is fine.  If you need columns from that table, add the appropriate `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: In your query you're saying to select the `pt.module_id`. Is that possible because of the `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @JeroenBellemans . . . Yes, that is how the query knows where to find the value of that column.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me (at least with the `WHERE` clause). Thanks alot!